# primitive_cube_add() creates only edges of cube

Tags: mesh, scripting

I am trying to understand how Blender deals with objects and data by experimenting a bit, starting from the default start-up screen.

I deleted the cube, looked how the stored objects and data responded and then tried to put the cube back, but I keep failing at the last step: I only get the edges of the cube, not the faces.
I first thought perhaps I needed to return to object mode explicitly, but if I uncomment that line it results in a "wrong context" - error.

Why can't I go to object mode, and why is only part of my cube coming back?

This is the code I ran:

```
# From startup screen:

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    ob.select = ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.name.startswith("Cube")
bpy.ops.object.delete()


print("Objects:" , list(bpy.data.objects)) # Camera, Lamp
print("Mesh data:", list(bpy.data.meshes)) # Cube ---> Cube data still exists!

print("Hello")

bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)

print("Bye")

print("Objects:" , list(bpy.data.objects)) # Camera, Lamp
print("Mesh data:", list(bpy.data.meshes)) # [] ---> Cube data gone!

# Back to startup configuration: add primitive cube

#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = (0,0,0), radius = 1)
```

Comment: The reason is probably that bpy.ops.object does not exist, because the active object was deleted. Try to activate the camera or something else.

Comment: @Dimali I selected the camera before running, and pasted 
`cam = bpy.context.active_object` 
before anything else in the script. At the end I included
`bpy.context.scene.objects.active = cam` before the primitive_add, but I still get edges only.

Comment: You are going to lose context after `bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)`  Recommend not saving files in script like this as it is not easily undone.  If you want to run code on load events and the like look at handlers.

Comment: @Gnub Selecting (by script) is not the same as activating, is the camera the active object?

Comment: @Dimali Sorry, yes I meant I made the camera active and then ran the code with the two exta lines from above comment.. Besides I don't get why the absense of an active object would prevent the primitive_cube_add from doing its job properly..

Comment: @Gnub Ok forget my comment. The mesh is correct after you switch to edit mode and back manually. Not sure how to fix it in code though.